# Why is my CSS file not linking properly to my HTML file?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web-development-server

I am currently working on a flask project with HTML templates.
the folder and sub folder is like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpAv8.png) image.

These are all the files.
Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/aboutAuthor')
def about_me():
    return render_template('about_me.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styled.css"/>
    <title>ShareIt</title>
</head>
<body>
to know more about me <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/aboutAuthor">click here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #4287f5;
    color: #eb4034;
    font-family: comicsans ms;
}

a:link{
    color: #fcba03;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #32a852;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color: #6832a8;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
    color: #943b81;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

It is showing the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Why is the CSS file not syncing with the HTML file?

Comment: Because you've ignored the basic flask setup. It's the [first example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/static/)

Comment: @roganjosh I would like it if you could go into a bit more detail, because I am not able to understand what the website you referenced is trying to say.

Comment: I would like to give clarification to everyone that my question is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem you can check the CSS file name in import statement.
That you wrote  
if it may be like this 
If this resolves your problem then OKAY otherwise I may require more details about your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).